# r raster changing extent removes data

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm attempting to figure out why I'm getting error messages with some simple raster algebra after changing the extent. To demonstrate this I thought I'd create a toy example following some code on another stack overflow question.

```
library(raster)    
## Create a matrix with random data
xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)

# generate two extents to apply
globeExtent <- extent(c(-180, 180, -90, 90))
smallerExtent <- extent(c(-180, 180, -59.5, 83.5))

# Turn the matrix into a raster
rast.smallextent <- raster(xy)
extent(rast.smallextent) <- smallerExtent

rast.globeExtent <- setExtent(rast.smallextent, ext = globeExtent, keepres = TRUE)
mathtest <- rast.globeExtent - rast.smallextent
```

The mathtest code line fails because rast.globeExtent has no values so I can't actually use this to test for the errors I was seeing elsewhere. How do I expand the extent of this raster without losing all its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret correctly the question, what you need to do is not to **change** the extent of `rast.smallextent`, but to **expand** the raster, using function `expand()`. Something like this:

```r
library(raster) 
#> Loading required package: sp
library(tmap)
## Create a matrix with random data
xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)

# generate two extents to apply
globeExtent   <- extent(c(-180, 180, -90, 90))
smallerExtent <- extent(c(-180, 180, -20, 20))

# Turn the matrix into a raster
rast.smallextent <- raster(xy)
extent(rast.smallextent) <- smallerExtent
tmap::tm_shape(rast.smallextent) + tmap::tm_raster() + tmap::tm_grid()
```

[image]

```r
# extend the raster over a wider area, while keeping the values
# 
rast.globeExtent  <- extend(rast.smallextent, globeExtent)

# Now rast.globeExtent is "expanded", but values are still there:

rast.globeExtent
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 90, 20, 1800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 18, 2  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : -3.606916, 2.795636  (min, max)
tmap::tm_shape(rast.globeExtent) + tmap::tm_raster() + tmap::tm_grid()
```

[image]

```r
# Math now works on the intersection, although results are "cropped" on 
# the intersecting area

rast.globeExtent <- rast.globeExtent + 1 #add 1 to check math is correct
mathtest <- rast.globeExtent - rast.smallextent
#> Warning in rast.globeExtent - rast.smallextent: Raster objects have different
#> extents. Result for their intersection is returned
mathtest
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 20, 20, 400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 18, 2  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -20, 20  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
tmap::tm_shape(mathtest) + tmap::tm_raster() + tmap::tm_grid()
```

[image]

HTH!

<sup>Created on 2019-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The difference in setExtent and extend are not clear from the terms used, and I had not thought to search beyond setExtent but your solution works and I learned a new part of the raster package. Before this came in I had found another solution. The extent was originally caused by using a polygon file to clip out Antarctica from a raster covering the globe. The clip process also reduced the extent of the raster. My solution was to grow the bounding box of the polygon file back to the whole lat long range. The specific code was `wrld_land@bbox <- bbox(rbind(c(-180, -90), c(180, 90)))`